# Need "Processes with Network Activity" functionality in managed code - Like resmon.exe does it

Tags: c#, networking, monitoring, process, android-activity

I am needing to collect a list (In C#) of processes which currently (Or within the past x secs) have have network activity, the names of the processes, and the qty of data sent (Pretty much EXACTLY what is shown on the new Windows 7 Resource Monitor under the network tab).

I know I could use WinPCap to write a complete sniffer myself, But I would prefer not to have the overhead, and I figured if I could do it the same way that win7 resmon.exe does it, I would be ahead of the game - Anyone have any info on how to do that in managed code without WinPCap?  Even if its not managed code, I would be happy to wrap it.

Comment: please don't duplicate tags like "C#" in the title. That's what tags are for.

Answer (score 0):

I know WMI has a number of network classes which give significant information about network activity. I would take a look in Win32 classes and then number operating system, then networking. Here is a link, hope it helps:

[WMI Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394554(v=VS.85).aspx)